# brew update broke something?

Tags: homebrew

Homebrew was working fine and normal till I did a `brew update` (haven't update for months). After brew update was finished, every `brew` command results in the same/similar error message:

```
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:6:in `require': no such file to load -- set (LoadError)
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:6 
    from /usr/local/bin/brew:17:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bin/brew:17
```

I checked the directory and it seems like the homebrew files are there. It is just not loading the file for some reason. I did a reinstall using git since `brew` command doesn't work. But still got the same error.

Any help on how I may resolve this issue is much appreciated. I might have to reinstall the os if I can't figure out anything.

Update: I did a clean install of the OS. Wasn't able to find a solution without reinstalling.

Comment: yes, a full reboot didn't do anything.

Answer (score 22):

I have met the same problem. And the following solved it:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local
cd /usr/local
git reset --hard origin/master
brew update
```

see https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/19140

Answer (score 3):

Do `brew doctor`

Examine the output and follow any recommendations given.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Brew doctor result the same error output.

Comment: This is an old question (and answer) but I just had this same issue pop up.  brew doctor gives the same errors as any other brew command, following a brew update.