# brew update has broken Homebrew

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I realised yesterday that I hadn't updated Homebrew since downloading a few months ago, so I decided to run `brew update`. Everything seemed to go fine, however now when I run any `brew` command (e.g. `brew doctor`) I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/compatibility (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

I had a look in that directory, and the rubygems/compatibility.rb file does indeed seem to be missing, but I'm not sure how/why that would have happened.

I tried reverting to a Time Machine backup from a few days ago and running the update again, but I'm seeing the exact same thing.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12240683/3362174) question, which seems to be very similar to my current situation, but none of the answers have fixed the issue. I can't even uninstall and then reinstall homebrew, as every set of uninstallation steps starts with `cd 'brew --prefix'` which  results in the same error as above.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Comment: `brew --prefix` just gives the place where you installed Homebrew, which is typically /usr/local, so you can use that instead. This seems like a problem with your Ruby environment; replacing Homebrew may not help. You might want to add a "ruby" tag.

Comment: @TimSmith - thanks for the heads up about adding 'ruby', have done so now. I played around a bit more last night and came to the same conclusion (which is that it's to do with the default OSX version of ruby). It's just odd that I didn't have any issues until I ran `brew update`.

Comment: You haven't updated to OSX Yosemite have you? I believe the default ruby version changed https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29795

Comment: Nope, just running the most recent version of Mavericks.